# How to use Firebase Device token (Android) as recipient Ids in salesforce custom notification Flow

Tags: firebase, push-notification, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-conntected-apps

I am trying to add android device token(Firebase)in the recipient ids of custom notification flow but its showing as an invalid parameter. But its working when I tried using a Test Push notification in salesforce using the same device token.

[[image: Error encountered when using Firebase device token as recipient Id]]

I have used my own app instead of salesforce app. I have followed this documentation https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_mobile_push_notifications_implementation.pdf.

My Firebase device token looks like this - dMDqotkLqXA:AaaaabGGdDv9ZpJGRjisqnCz2AyG9AahfGfJJXfuXKqKgYj6RRI8owNNIPR04x6NT7bB4NsRVGgL00Ii-ai0Nbfh7IbnkD5oGS8UoHv6gectuEL-*M8digrQQHU0ETpKoFbpb4abmE0*